# C#-cannot view properties of a reference in bin folder

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, office-interop, com-interop

[Click here for screenshot.on clicking the reference it is not showing the properties, How to set embed interop type to false?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0BfX.png)

Comment: witch properties you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your .csproj file.. Edit it and Change the value to False

```
 <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
```

Exemple of .csproj file :

```
<ItemGroup>
....
     <Reference Include="Microsoft.mshtml, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
....
</ItemGroup>
```